# How can I get the current usage of TTLCache?

Tags: python

I am using `TTLCache` in my python application.

```
from cachetools import TTLCache
ts_cache = TTLCache(maxsize=50000, ttl=300)
```

I wonder whether I can know how many data has been cached in TTLCache instance.
I can't find it from its document: https://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Are you looking for `currsize` of cache?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

From the document [link](https://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#cachetools.Cache.currsize) provided in OP.

You can use `currsize` for *The current size of the cache.*

```
>>> from cachetools import TTLCache
>>> ts_cache = TTLCache(maxsize=50000, ttl=300)
>>> ts_cache.currsize
0
```